# How to do aggregate functions such as count in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

I have this SQL that I would like to execute in Entity Framework Core 2.1:

```
Select ItemTypeId, Count(ItemTypeId) as Count from Items i 
where i.ParentId = 2
group by ItemTypeId
```

How do I do that?

This is what I came up with, but it returns zero:

```
var query = this._context.Items.Where(a => a.ParentId == 2)
.GroupBy(i => new { i.ItemTypeId })
.Select(g => new { g.Key.ItemTypeId, Count = g.Count(i=> i.ItemTypeId == g.Key.ItemTypeId) });

var items = query.ToList();
```

The only example I could find was [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1)

Comment: `g.Count()` should be enough.

Comment: Thank you, that does work.  If you want to post as answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `Count = g.Count(i=> i.ItemTypeId == g.Key.ItemTypeId)`, instead use `g.Count()`.